# How to do batch put using HBase Thrift Node.js?

Tags: node.js, hbase, thrift

I have generated node.js code for HBase thrift and written code which puts single row in HBase by using `mutateRow()` method. I would like to know how can I put multiple rows in single API call of `mutateRow()` method to improve performance? My current code is as follows :

```
connection.on('connect', function(){
  console.log('connected to hbase.');
  var dummyCol1 = {'family' : 'CF', 'qualifier':'CF:dummy_col_1', 'value':'dummy_val'};
  var colVal = new TColumnValue(dummyCol1);

  var putJs = {'row' : 'dummy_rk_for_testing_thrift_mutateRow_method','columnValues' : [colVal]};
  var put = new TPut(putJs);
  
  var mute = new TMutation({'put' : put});

  var m1 = new TRowMutations({'row' : 'dummy_rk_for_testing_thrift_mutateRow_method', 'mutations' : [mute]});

  client.mutateRow('COMPANY_TABLE', m1, function(err){
    if(err) {
      console.log('some error occurred in put operation.');
     console.dir(err);
    } else {
      console.log('success !!!');
    }
  });
    connection.end();
});
```

Above code works and creates a new row in HBase but when I execute following code :

```
connection.on('connect', function(){
  console.log('connected to hbase.');
  var dummyCol1 = {'family' : 'CF', 'qualifier':'CF:dummy_col_1', 'value':'dummy_val'};
  var colVal = new TColumnValue(dummyCol1);

  var putJs = {'row' : 'dummy_rk_for_testing_thrift_mutateRow_method','columnValues' : [colVal]};
  var put = new TPut(putJs);

  var putJs2 = {'row' : 'dummy_rk_2_for_testing_thrift_mutateRow_method','columnValues' : [colVal]};
  var put2 = new TPut(putJs2);

  var mute = new TMutation({'put' : put});
  var mute2 = new TMutation({'put' : put2});

  var m1 = new TRowMutations({'row' : 'dummy_rk_for_testing_thrift_mutateRow_method', 'mutations' : [mute]});
  var m2 = new TRowMutations({'row' : 'dummy_rk_2_for_testing_thrift_mutateRow_method', 'mutations' : [mute2]});

  client.mutateRow('COMPANY_TABLE', [m1, m2], function(err){
    if(err) {
      console.log('some error occurred in put operation.');
     console.dir(err);
    } else {
      console.log('success !!!');
     console.dir(err);
    }
  });
    connection.end();
});
```

I get following error :

```
/home/ubuntu/shekhar/thrift/client/gen-nodejs/THBaseService.js:2321
    this.rowMutations.write(output);
                      ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.THBaseService_mutateRow_args.write (/home/ubuntu/shekhar/thrift/client/gen-nodejs/THBaseService.js:2321:23)
    at Object.THBaseServiceClient.send_mutateRow (/home/ubuntu/shekhar/thrift/client/gen-nodejs/THBaseService.js:3317:8)
    at Object.THBaseServiceClient.mutateRow (/home/ubuntu/shekhar/thrift/client/gen-nodejs/THBaseService.js:3307:10)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/shekhar/thrift/client/multi-put.js:39:10)
    at emit (events.js:104:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/shekhar/thrift/client/node_modules/thrift/lib/thrift/connection.js:73:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1001:10)
```

What can I try to resolve this?